# Take picture into OneNote from Microsoft LifeCam

Tags: camera, microsoft-onenote

I have MS LifeCam but can't take snapshot from it into MS OneNote program. Cameras and scanners button does not allow to acquire from this camera.

Is it possible to use this camera to capture still images with this camera?

I know I can capture a screen.

Comment: I'm sorry but do you want a screenshot of OneNote or insert a picture into OneNote?

Comment: I want to insert picture of real world into OneNote by few clicks.

Comment: So you can do "insert picture" in OneNote right? After you take the photo and save it?

Comment: I find it ridiculous that I can take video with my webcam and place it into OneNote, but if I want to take a photo using that same camera it doesn't work and says there's no imaging device. Pathetic.